# JavaScript/Selenium - scroll to li inside ul

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have a dropdown which html is `list` - `<ul><li><a></a></li>...`

This dropdown is scrollable and I need to make `Selenium` to scroll to `<a>` with certain `id` because I can't click on it unless it's visible.

It is probably possible using `JavaScript` but can't figure out how to make it work.

```
clickable_a_id - id of <a> element which I want to scroll to

self.driver.execute_script(
    # 'arguments[0].scrollTop = document.getElementById("{}").offsetTop + 5 '.format(clickable_a_id),
    'document.getElementById("{}")[0].scrollIntoView()'.format(clickable_a_id),UL_ELEMENT)
```

It does not work. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: You have to `scroll inside the view` (**not** `scrollIntoView()` by JS ). Share the relevant `HTML` and you last code trial.

Answer (score 2):

did you try using action ?

```
    el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("")
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(el).perform()
```

you can scroll further with

```
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,20)")
```

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to a specific element using Id, you can implement `JavascriptExecutor` like below:

```
//Use some delay like wait.until or sleep

WebElement elem =  driver.findElement(By.id("clickable_a_id"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem);

//Use some delay like wait.until or sleep
```

PS. *You might(or not) need to use some sort of delay for visibility of Id element.* 
First, try without using delay.

Comment: @MilanoS Brother! try to implement the answer that I've posted and let me know your feedback.